# How to convert a Plotly 'Funnel' Dashboard to Dash Dashboard?

Tags: python, graph, anaconda, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am trying to convert this simple plotly funnel dashboard to a Dash dashboard:

```
from plotly import graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Funnel(
    y = ["Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent"],
    x = [39, 27.4, 20.6, 11, 2]))

fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]

I have written the following piece of code for Dash but no luck.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from plotly import graph_objects as go

app = dash.Dash()


app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Figure(id='FunnelDashboard',
                    figure = {'data':[
                            go.Funnel(
                            y = ["Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent"],
                            x = [39, 27.4, 20.6, 11, 2])]
                            }
                            )])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Test\Documents\Code>python Funnel_Dash.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Funnel_Dash.py", line 23, in <module>
    app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Figure(id='FunnelDashboard',
AttributeError: module 'dash_core_components' has no attribute 'Figure'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Figure` is not an attribute of `dash_core_components`.

We can use `Graph` instead.

```
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='FunnelDashboard',
                    figure = {'data':[
                            go.Funnel(
                            y = ["Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent"],
                            x = [39, 27.4, 26.6, 11, 2])]
                            }
                            )])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
app.layout=html.Div([
                    dcc.Graph(
                    id='chart1',
                    figure=fig
                )
        ])
```