# Plotly-Dash displays the wrong graph (line plot instead of funnel)

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am trying to display a simple funnel graph using dash and plotly. The problem is that it displays a line graph instead.

I followed the instructions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59069605) answer, that is, used the code:

```
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='FunnelDashboard',
                figure = {'data':[
                        go.Funnel(
                        y = ["Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent"],
                        x = [39, 27.4, 26.6, 11, 2])]
                        }
                        )])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

but am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP8od.png) line plot instead.

What I expect to get is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmIn7.png).

Comment: Running the above code, I do get a funnel plot as you describe. So something else must be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update dash:

```
pip install -U dash
```

With version `1.9.1`, using this code:

```py
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from plotly import graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Funnel(
    y = ["Website visit", "Downloads", "Potential customers", "Requested price", "invoice sent"],
    x = [39, 27.4, 20.6, 11, 2]))


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)


app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Graph(id='FunnelDashboard',
                    figure=fig)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

you get:

[image]